# panel with buttons doesn't appear on trumbowyg plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, trumbowyg

I'm using a plugin for javascript to have an HTML Editor (WYSIWYG), called Trumbowyg. no errors appear when instantiating an creating elementes with this plugin, but for some reason that I want to discover, the panel with the buttons/options doesn't show up.

My Code:

```
        var editorHtmlElement = document.createElement('textarea');
        editorHtmlElement.className = "col-md-6";           
        editorHtmlElement.setAttribute('placeholder', 'placeholder...');
        var OptionsTrumbowyg = {};

        OptionsTrumbowyg.btns = [
            ['undo', 'redo'],
            ['justifyLeft', 'justifyCenter', 'justifyRight', 'justifyFull'],
            ['formatting'],
            ['strong', 'em', 'del'],
            ['link'],
            ['insertImage'],
            ['unorderedList', 'orderedList'],
            ['horizontalRule'],
            ['removeformat'],
        ];
        OptionsTrumbowyg.autogrow = true;  

        var editorHtmljQuery = $(editorHtmlElement);

        editorHtmljQuery.trumbowyg(OptionsTrumbowyg);
```

After that, I append the editorHtmlElement to a div or whatever.
EXPECTED:
[image]

WHAT I'M GETTING
[image]
As you can see, no panel with buttons appear, even if I try with no custom options just the default... Anyone knows why? 
(No errors appears)

Comment: Are you sure that your code has the `<link>` to the `css` file?

Comment: absolutely, it is an Asp net project with a bundleConfig... and as I said, no errors about loading appears and also in the devTools under network, I can see the files loaded

Comment: @CalvinNunes could you make a jsfiddle to show the issue? Easier that way?

Comment: I don't know if it will work because there isn't a direct link to trumbowyg that I can use in the external resources of jsfiddle, and it also need a .svg file (that i load in the project and no errors appears)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Managed to make it working by adding the Trumbowyg after all appends and includes of CSS, and changing the 
 `var editorHtmlElement = document.createElement('textarea');`
 to
`var editorHtmlElement = document.createElement('div');`

Just moved the 
 `editorHtmljQuery.trumbowyg(OptionsTrumbowyg);`
 for the end of all scripts when loading the page, then it worked well